# Deduplicate by column (1, 2) but also deduplicate by column (2,1)

Tags: vba, excel

This is my current attempt:

```
Sub DeleteRows()

With ActiveSheet
    Set Rng = Range("A1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
    Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
End With

End Sub
```

The problem is that this only references column 1 for deduplication before moving to column 2. So

```
HOME|AWAY|DATE
================
MARK|PAUL|JUNE1
PAUL|MARK|JUNE5
Sara|JOHN|JUNE8
JOHN|SARA|JUNE12
```

doesn't deduplicate. What I'm trying to achieve is for my code to treat those rows the same, even though they are not. That way I only have the first day of the month these two competitors played. Below is the ultimate result I'm looking for.

```
HOME|AWAY|DATE
================
MARK|PAUL|JUNE1
Sara|JOHN|JUNE8
```

Hopefully it is clear what I'm asking. I've racked my brain a little. The only thing I can come up with is some convoluted method by which I flip flop the columns and deduplicate twice. But that seems inefficient.

Comment: It's a hard one, isn't it?

Comment: so that method would dedup Mark, Paul and Paul, Mark all the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do another column with combined names. This new column would sort the two names alphabetically so that Mark always comes before Paul and John always comes before Sara. Then de-duplicate on this new column.

Pseudo code:

```
For each row in rng

    'do a bubble sort on the two names to determine alphabetical order
    'enter in a new column as Name Name like: JOHN PAUL

next

'de-duplicate on the new column
```

[Bubble sort procedure](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/830b42cf-8c97-4aaf-b34b-d860773281f7/sorting-an-array-in-vba-without-excel-function?forum=isvvba)

Basically the idea is that if you have two players you need to use bubble sort to determine which is first alphabetically. Then you enter it as MARK PAUL instead of PAUL MARK so your data is consistent. When you're done with the sort process, Mark will always come before Paul. Now your de-dupe will work as you expect.

After the bubble sort your data will look like this:

```
HOME|AWAY|DATE  |Sorted names
=============================
MARK|PAUL|JUNE1 |MARK PAUL
PAUL|MARK|JUNE5 |MARK PAUL
Sara|JOHN|JUNE8 |JOHN SARA
JOHN|SARA|JUNE12|JOHN SARA
```

Now the de-dupe will work as expected on the new column.

EDIT:

Actually never mind the bubble sort. This formula is all you need to create the new column:

```
=UPPER(IF(B2<A2,B2&"_"&A2,A2&"_"&B2))
```

Comment: Thanks for spelling it out for me. Much appreciated!

Comment: False positives if someone called `MA` plays against someone called `RK PAUL`. (You may think this example is contrived, but actually there are two people with those exact names in my company! In the general case this will happen, because many people have spaces in their names.) To guard against this, use as a delimiter not a space but a character that is unlikely to appear in any name e.g. `MARK#PAUL`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Using a special delimiter is good in case you need to split the names later. Also in case you have one person named `John Mark` and another named simply `John`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Not sure what you mean by "False positive"; we're just doing a sort; it doesn't matter the length of the name. We're not doing any sort of positive/negative test. Still I agree about the special character but not for the reason you mention.

Comment: I meant that with a space delimiter, a game between "Jean François" and "Xavier" is going to be put in the same bin as a game between "Jean" and "François Xavier", even though these are four different people and you don't want those games to be put in the same bin. That's why you should use an unambiguous delimiter -- e.g. `_` as in your now corrected Excel formula.

Comment: Yeah, that last example was better than the first one! I now see that the first one wasn't good.